# Soundcloud API Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception HTTP code 0

Tags: php, soundcloud

I am using the example code from the Soundcloud API Docs.
But nothing seems to work:

```
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// create a client object with your app credentials
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');

// find all sounds of buskers licensed under 'creative commons share alike'
$tracks = $client->get('tracks', array('q' => 'buskers', 'license' => 'cc-by-sa'));
```

I have corrected the obvious mistake in the example code to include the CLIENT_SECRET
but i just get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception' with message 'The requested URL responded with HTTP code 0.

Any ideas? I can't believe they don't provide examples that actually work.

Comment: The error message says the that web site is returning an invalid status. You should verify the site is working properly before worrying about the code.